# Interactive Media Ads for android application

Tags: android, ads, adsense, advertisement-server

I've been developing a live streaming/video player into my `Android` application.In that we have to implement pre/mid/post ads integration for which I've tried Google's `IMA SDK`. In the sample app, from video player(`IMA SDK`). We have to request(using ad tags) ads from VAST compliant ad servers like google `AdSense`.So,basically the ads positioning and timing is controlled by the video player logic.But our requirement is, the entire ad control should be done by the ad servers.Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using [DFP ad rules](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1406475?hl=en). With ad rules, you can [define cue points](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1406418?hl=en) (from DFP) when new ad requests should be made. Once done, you will get an ad tag to feed into the IMA SDK. The SDK will make the request, and based on the current time, if the time matches the pre-defined cue point, the SDK will make the ad request automatically.

When it is time to play the ad, the SDK will fire [`CONTENT_PAUSE_REQUESTED`](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/v3/apis#ima.AdEvent.Type.CONTENT_PAUSE_REQUESTED), and you can hide the video player control depending on your requirements.